# Validate input value, if it's wrong than set default

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to write a validation of my input field value.
If the value is wrong then I want to set a default value.
Unfortunately it's checking it, set the default value and later is set the wrong value.
I'm trying to use the extender validation. Before I tried with the "subscribe" But Again without success. Here is my example about scenario

> On start in input I have 0.56
>   I'm changing it to 0.95 . So the extender is checking that the 0.95 is grosser than 0.85 and is changing the value to 0.85. Unfortunately in my case is still 0.95. I add some alert after- target(0.85) I can see that value is changing to 0.85 but after that is again 0.95.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
ko.extenders.checkInput = function (target) {

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,
        write: function (newValue) {

            if (newValue > 0.85) {
                target(0.85);
            } 

         });

    //return the new computed observable
    result(target());

    return result;


};

self.inputValue = ko.observable(0.56).extend({ checkInput: '' });
```

Comment: Except from the missing bracket, this seems to work fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/a75oqxtw/

Comment: If it's written like that is working. Unfortunately when I have input field in front end it's not working

Comment: Could you try to reproduce your situation with http://jsfiddle.net. I think maybe you're not using the extended observable in the input.

Comment: Unfortunately I have some issue with jsfiddle tha's why I create my example in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ovKkg) first change is validated but latest not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use notifySubscribers if the value doesn't change and extend the computed to always notify about a change (as per [knockout documentation on extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)):

```
ko.extenders.checkInput = function(target, option) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
            valueToWrite = Math.min(newValue, 0.85);
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
    result(target());

    return result;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w017dc50/

Comment: Hi @Jerry. Thank you very much. In CodePen is working. So I will check your post like a answer. Unfortunately in my solution is not beacuse I have a custom binding to display this value. Unfortunately with custom binding is not working(please check [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ovKkg))

Comment: Had a quick look, but there seems to be a separate issue with your custom binding. I think there is a clash between ko.utils.registerEventHandler in the init part and the update art ifself (you don't need both).

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating `target` if the value passes the validation. Try this:

```
ko.extenders.checkInput = function (target) {

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,
        write: function (newValue) {
            target(Math.min(newValue, 0.85));
        }
    });

    //return the new computed observable
    result(target());

    return result;
};
```

Comment: I still have the same issue. The first time is updating but later isn't @Jerry already share a working solution.